# Adding items to page template dropdown on Page Edit Screen

Tags: theme-development, page-template, mvc

I am developing a WP theme with MVC approach. It only have `index.php`, `functions.php` and `styles.css` on the parent directory. So, I do not want to place page templates on it rather then I want to programmatically provide them from View classes while functionality from edit screen stays the same.

Users need to have page templates select option on the edit screen. How do I successfully add Items to the template dropdown?

I tried to hook into [`theme_page_templates`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php#L1022) filter.

**Example code:**

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', function($templates){

    $templates['my-page-template.php'] = "My Page Template";

    return $templates;

});
```

This does not work because of the use of [`array_intersect_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) on the filtered array, which removes the added page template item. I don't understand why this function is used. It seems you can only remove page template from the list but can not add a new one using the given filter.

Is there any other way around?

Comment: I remember playing with this [filter here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188647/26350), when I wanted to add extra info to the template dropdown, like usage statistics. But this part stopped me too at that time ;-) I haven't revisit it since, but there might be workarounds, like with javascript or through a custom metabox.

Comment: @birgire - Check my answer for this as I think you can do what you want using the approach I posted.

Comment: Have a look to this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143054/35541 I'm using this trick and works pretty well

Comment: Thanks for sharing @gmazzap, just noticed your link ;-) It's now easier in WordPress 4.4+, I just reviewed this again in my old linked answer above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I would provide you with another approach. It is also a bit hackish, but it is general purpose and allows you to simply register the filename and label that you want to use, like so:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPSE_196995_Page_Templates' ) ) {   
    WPSE_196995_Page_Templates::register_page_template(
        'My Page Template',
        'my-page-template.php'
    );
}
```

You could add the above code to your theme's `functions.php` file.

To enable the above to actually work I implemented a self-contained class that could be used as a plugin or just copied into `functions.php`:

```
<?php   
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 196995 Page Templates
 *
 * Class WPSE_196995_Page_Templates
 *
 * Allows registering page templates via code.
 */
class WPSE_196995_Page_Templates {

    static $registered_templates = array();

    static function on_load() {

        /**
         * Add registered page templates to 'page_template' cache.
         * @note This hook is called just before page templates are loaded
         */
        add_action( 'default_page_template_title', array( __CLASS__, '_default_page_template_title' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Register page templates
     *
     * @param string $label
     * @param string $filename
     */
    static function register_page_template( $label, $filename ) {

        self::$registered_templates[ $filename ] = $label;

    }

    /**
     * Add registered page templates to 'page_template' cache.
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return string mixed
     */
    static function _default_page_template_title( $title ) {

        /**
         * @var WP_Theme $theme
         */
        $theme = wp_get_theme();

        /**
         * Access the cache the hard way since WP_Theme makes almost everything private
         */
        $cache_hash = md5( $theme->get_stylesheet_directory() );

        /**
         * Get the page templates as the 'page_templates' cache will already be primed
         */
        $page_templates = wp_cache_get( $key = "page_templates-{$cache_hash}", $group = 'themes' );

        /**
         * Add in registered page templates
         */
        $page_templates += self::$registered_templates;

        /**
         * Now update the cache, which is what the get_page_templates() uses.
         */
        wp_cache_set( $key, $page_templates, $group, 1800 );

        /**
         * We are using this hook as if it were an action.
         * So do not modify $title, just return it.
         */
        return $title;

    }

}
WPSE_196995_Page_Templates::on_load();
```

The class provides the `register_page_template()` method, of course, but to actually add your page template it updates the value for `'page_templates'` set in the object cache.

It is a bit hacky because WordPress made most methods and properties of the `WP_Theme` class `private`, but fortunately they used the publicly-accessible WordPress object cache to store the values. And by updating the object cache in the `'default_page_template_title'` hook, which is called just before the page templates dropdown is generated and sent to the browser, we can get WordPress to display your page template(s), as you desired.

Comment: What a creative workaround, thanks for sharing - I look forward to test&play ;-)

Comment: I thought about adding to the cache some point using the WP_Theme class. But everything can be use as a work around is private on the class. Your implementation is very clever indeed :) I will try it out and let you know..

Comment: The method worked! I had to change the hook to `admin_head` with appropriate conditionals. Somehow adding to the filter didn't worked for me.

Comment: @Sisir - So the `'default_page_template_title'` hook did not work but `'admin_head'` did? But ultimately you got it working?

Comment: Yep, Probably I did something wrong on the filter but it was running out of time so used `admin_head` and didn't gave much though why the filter didn't worked.

Comment: @Sisir - Okay, cool.

Answer (score 1):

Got around with a ugly hack :-/. I will update the answer If I go with jQuery later on. The solution still requires to have template files but code for the template file loads from the `index.php`

1. I made a new `template/` directory and put all page template there.
2. All page templates are blank. We need it only for them to show up on the dropdown.
3. Use `template_include` filter to redirect to `index.php`

### Code

**Blank Page Template Example**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: No Sidebar
 *
 * */
```

**Filter**

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function ($template ) {

    if ( !is_page_template()  )
        return $template;

    return locate_template( array( 'index.php' ), true );

}, 99);
```

[I have created a trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33309) to allow adding templates via filter.